# Can't get any PhoneGap plugins to work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I just did a completely fresh install of PhoneGap, Cordova, and the PhoneGap Desktop App.

I made a new app using the Desktop app, and no matter what plugins I try, none of them work.  No errors appear in the console, there just isn't any activity happening.

I've tried 3 different Bluetooth LE plugins, the Toaster plugin (for dialogs), and a few others.

Am I missing something?  Is there something I should check?

According to a lot of plugin documentation, I should be able to access window.plugins, but every app I create, window.plugins is undefined.

According to documentation of these plugins, all I need to do is cordova plugin add  and they should be accessible from within my HTML file, but they're not.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your Config.xml please? Also, how do you preview your project: by using the phoneGap's app? or do you build and install on your phone?

Comment: are you testing on the phonegap mobile apps? Or you build the apps and test on the device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat confused on what PhoneGap Desktop App is, but it looks like it's emulating a mobile device. But Bluetooth LE won't work on iOS or Android emulators, you'll need to test Bluetooth LE code on a real device.